# Convert HTML to PDF using Python with format PDF/X-1a

Tags: python, django, pdf, xhtml2pdf

I have a website that converts HTML to PDFs using a library in Django called "**XHTML2PDF**".

The problem is that I need to convert this PDF using **PDF/X-1a** format. I don't know if it's possible to change the format in XHTML2PDF if not, anyone knows an alternative?

View:

```
 def book(request):
        # Prepare context
        data = {}
        data['today'] = datetime.date.today()
        data['farmer'] = 'Old MacDonald'
        data['animals'] = [('Cow', 'Moo'), ('Goat', 'Baa'), ('Pig', 'Oink')]

        # Render html content through html template with context
        template = get_template('book_number_one.html')
        html  = template.render(Context(data))

        # Write PDF to file
        file = open('test.pdf', "w+b")
        pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file,
                encoding='utf-8')

        # Return PDF document through a Django HTTP response
        file.seek(0)
        pdf = file.read()
        file.close()            # Don't forget to close the file handle
        return HttpResponse(pdf, mimetype='application/pdf')
```

Template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Background</title>
        <style>
            @page p1 {
                background-image: url("nu/COVER-FRONT-ES.png");
                size: 210mm 210mm;
                @frame text {
                    top: 6cm;
                    left: 4cm;
                    right: 4cm;
                    bottom: 4cm;
                }
            }
            @page p2 {
                background-image: url("nu/001.png");
                size: 210mm 210mm;
                @frame text {
                    top: 6cm;
                    left: 4cm;
                    right: 4cm;
                    bottom: 4cm;
                    border:0;
                }
            }
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Gilles';
                src: url(/gilles/gilles.ttf);
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pdf:nextpage name="p1" />

        <pdf:nextpage name="p2" />

        <p class="page-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br />
            Vitae, natus, possimus, placeat consequuntur iste at sapiente perferendis <br />
            delectus suscipit dolorem dignissimos quaerat quia ex fuga officia dolore <br />
            asperiores sint mollitia.<br />
            <br />
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think that is PDF/X-1a by default.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a library called '**django-easy-pdf**'

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-easy-pdf

Demo : [here](https://easy-pdf.herokuapp.com/)

```
{% extends "easy_pdf/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Hi there!</h1>
    </div>
{% endblock %}


from easy_pdf.views import PDFTemplateView

class HelloPDFView(PDFTemplateView):
    template_name = "hello.html"
```